# Linear time parsing from star of context free language

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata, parsers

I was wondering if there are cases in which the star closure of a language can make the resulting language easier to parse. In particular, if I have this grammar:

```
S -> c|AS|A
A -> aAa|bAb|e
```

I can see that $L(A) = \{x x^R : x \in \Sigma^*\}$ (where $x^R$ denotes the reverse of $x$). That language is not even deterministic context free since I can't determine where the switch from $x$ to $x^R$ happens looking at the top of the stack only.

Using Arden's rule, I noticed that $L(S) = L(A)^* c + L(A)^*$. So, is it possible to parse $L(S)$ without nondeterminism? I thought that a string $w$ like $aaabbaaa$ could be seen, in $L(S)$, as a concatenation of $w_1 w_2 w_3$ where $w_1 = aa$, $w_2 = abba$, $w_3 = aa$. As for this word in particular, an automaton could recognize and accept the strings by inspecting only one stack symbol at a time. Could this be generalized in some way for the whole language $L(S)$ of the example?

In particular, is $L(A)^*$ a deterministic context-free language?  Can it be accepted by a deterministic pushdown automaton?

Comment: Are you asking whether for any context-free language $L$, the language $L^*$ is always deterministic context-free? If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: No, I am asking if it is possible in general that this happens (not always, but in particular cases) and specifically I thought of this example to understand better. I am sorry, I did not express myself in a clear way

Comment: So are you asking either or both of the following questions? (1) Is there a context-free language $L$ which is not deterministic context-free such that $L^*$ is deterministic context-free? (2) Is $L^*$ deterministic context-free, where $L = \{ xx^R : x \in \Sigma^* \}$?

Comment: The second one :)

Comment: OK.  I suggest you edit the question to say that -- I too found it hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I hope it is more clear now :)

Comment: No, I still can't tell what you're asking.  "Could this be generalized" - I'm not sure what "this" means.  What was wrong with the way that Yuval Films phrased it?  If what Yuval wrote is what you're trying to ask, your question seems like a convoluted and unclear way to ask if.  I can't see the relationship between Yuval's phrasing and what you wrote.

Comment: Other things that confuse me: I don't tell what the statement "However, since..." is saying.  What do you mean by "for Arden's rule"?  "recognize and accept the strings" - the strings of what?  I tried editing the question to add Yuval's formulation but I still don't understand what you were trying to write.  Check my edit, as I might have misunderstood what you were trying to say.  It would help if you could be more precise about exactly what your question is.

Comment: "could this be generalized" = Can I parse it with a deterministic pda or did I just pick a particular example?

Comment: Arden's rule because the language equation for L(S) allows me to apply Arden's rule and obtain an expression for L(S). Nothing was wrong with Yuval Filmus's phrase, I meant the same thing since I gave the example just to see a concrete case

Comment: Your language is probably not deterministic context-free (if I had to guess), but this is probably messy to prove.

Comment: I did have a suspect about that, I was asked whether I could parse L(S) in linear time but that does not seem easy, or at all possible...